# Why are the two results different in YOLOv5?

Tags: python, object-detection, yolo, yolov5

I wanted to know the number of vehicles in the picture using yolov5
However, the result of the model was different from detect.py

**0. img**
[image: enter image description here.]

**1. model_result**

```
# Model
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s')  # or yolov5m, yolov5l, yolov5x, custom

# Images
img = 'D:\code\YOLO\dataset\img\public02.png'  # or file, Path, PIL, OpenCV, numpy, list

# Inference
results = model(img)

# Results
results.print()  # or .show(), .save(), .crop(), .pandas(), etc.
```

result -> `(no detections)`

**2. detect.py**

```
from IPython.display import Image
import os

val_img_path = 'D:\code\YOLO\dataset\img\public02.png'
 
!python detect.py --img 416 --conf 0.25 --source "{val_img_path}"
```

result ->
[image: enter image description here too]

I know that if I don't specify weight option in detect.py, the default yolo5s model is used.
but, Result 1 differs from Result 2 using the same model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is an image processing issue.

Indeed with your example, the model loaded from torch hub gives a different output than `detect.py`. Looking at the source code of `detect.py` I see that there is some good image pre-processing. From the model hub, I really don't know what's happening to the input. From the model hub, the resulting image is this:

[image: Torch hub model]

With their pre-processing, this is basically the image that you are feeding into the model. Would not expect any detections from this to be honest.

But then I tried doing the pre-processing myself (noted as well in their [tutorial](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/36))

```
import torch
import cv2

# Model
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s')  # or yolov5m, yolov5l, yolov5x, custom

# Image
imgPath = '/content/9X9FP.png'
img = cv2.imread(imgPath)[..., ::-1]  # Pre-processing OpenCV image (BGR to RGB)

# Inference
results = model(img)

# Results
results.save()
```

And it all works fine:

[image: Good detections]

So for a quick and easy answer, I would just do the pre-processing my self, it's just a simple one line extra step. Good luck!